# ProgressDialog in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is loader from my list

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(
                getActivity(), null, "Loading...");

        super.onPreExecute();
    }
```

I have 8 tabs in app, they are all almost same, difference is that load different content... 
When I open my app, they all show at the same time, I wont to chane that to just selected fragment...

Answer (score 0):

I use a layout that looks something like this:

```
<ViewSwitcher ...>
   <ProgressBar indetermiate="true" />
   <!-- Insert actual content here -->
</ViewSwitcher>
```

Then you can use the code in your fragment to control the switching between the loading page and the content.